# How to discover which technology is used by an iframe like on Google Docs or Sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know they use an Iframe. When inspecting the HTML, it's not possible to find the content of cells. I don't know much about Iframes, but I know they enable your website to display documents, media, interactive content, etc from an outside source.

It's easy to incorporate youtube videos on your website using an Iframe, for example.

But in the end, which technology is actually running google sheets? If it's HTML+CSS+JS, can I investigate the source code somehow? If not, Is there an easy way to discover it?

Comment: Yes, there is. Simply look at its source code. Since the websites (probably) block those shortcuts or rewrite it (such as underline on Google Docs), click the URL, then press Ctrl + U. You can also use Ctrl + Shift + I, however, that allows you to see the elements on the page currently, but that can be changed dynamically by the javascript present in the actual source code.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I managed to inspect plaintext html of the source code. It ends up being redered to HTML in the end. If you answer the question i'll pick yours

Comment: No need - just glad I could help!

Comment: Also just a warning beforehand, the actual code is *EXTREMELY* complicated. If you're trying to write an extension or manipulate the HTML, then it's better to use the console, and if you're trying to do something else (such as read or write to a doc), it's better to use the Google Docs API.

Comment: In addition to the Google Docs API, there is the Google Apps Scripts, which allows you to do things a little bit more directly, but has somewhat limited functionality. This was probably implemented for those who wanted something extra, but didn't want to integrate the full-blown API, because that's quite difficult and time-consuming.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: No problem! If you need any further help let me know - while I don't have a ton of 'experience', I do have some ;).